# Solution to load custom CSS, every time a page(internet, not local) is loaded on my browser?

Tags: css, browser

Example.

I make some CSS changes on the Google home page. I want to save the CSS(somewhere) and have the same appearance every time I load the page.

Any browser plugin or any other method is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Google Chrome, there is an extension called "Stylebot" which I think may be just what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will check it.